# As BIDS 2008 is only 32 bit how can we develop for 64 bit?

Tags: ssis, 64-bit, driver, bids, dsn

I am working to get my packages running on SSIS 2008 64 bit. My pacakges used DSN so I made 64 bit DSN.. but as BIDS is only 32 bit I run into error like below.

[image]

I think .Net Provider\Odbc Data Provider is 32 bit (as it is part of BIDS 32 bit) but My DSN is 64 bit so error. What can be solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since BIDS is a 32 bit application, you need to create a 32 bit DSN using the odbc administrator application in the Windows\SysWOW64 folder.

I like this article...

http://timlaqua.com/2011/11/ssis-bids-and-64bit-system-dsns-whos-on-first/

Comment: I think SSIS is available as both 32 and 64 bit. BIDS is only 32 bit.. I was wonsering if I want to run SSIS 64 bit in production how can i do development? 64 bit SSIS might look for a 64 bit DSN!

Comment: I would think you could create the DSN on the SSIS server with the same name and it would pick it up.  I amended my answer replacing SSIS with BIDS - I really meant BIDS.